# How can I split data from a second dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two tables in SSRS. One holds the amount of insurance claims in a given month and one holds the amount of insurance complaints in a given month

Each table is calculated by either `=COUNT(Fields!Claims.Value)` for claims and `=COUNT(Fields!Complaints.Value)` that is simple enough and is split over the current 10 months of a year

Where it gets tricky though is that the claims table has an additional line where it calculates complaints as a ratio of claims. My current expression reads as follows:

```
=COUNT(Fields!Complaints.Value, "Complaints"/=COUNT(Fields!Claims.Value)
```

but the problem I have is that it's taking the full YTD value of the complaints and dividing by the monthly amount of claims.

**ASK:**
 How can I get a calculation similar to above but only dividing complaints by month and claims by month - but keeping in mind that the complaints data comes from a different table

Comment: If I understand your question, you have a dataset for complaints, another for claims. you want to calculate complaints/claims by month. right? If so is there a month field in each dataset?

Comment: hi Alejandro yes they both run off of a field called 'CallMonth' - so there is a common link there

Comment: Before guess a possible solution could you provide sample data about both datasets and a short example of your expected result.

Comment: For example in the claims table in January there were 140 claims
in the complaints table there were 10 complaints 

Therefore the result I would like is 10/140 = 7.1%

But unfortunately my current expression which is written as follows

=COUNT(Fields!Complaints.Value, "Complaints"/=COUNT(Fields!Claims.Value) 

Is calculating 62 (which is the total yearly amount of complaints) divided by 140 (the amount of claims for Jan) So i need the expression to only pick out the 10 complaints for january

With both of these coming from a 'CallMonth' field

ThanksD

Comment: How do you want to present the result table. grouping by month?

Comment: yes that's right Alejandro, I would like to group by month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LookupSet function to get the claims in the same month.

1. Create a tablix and use the `Complaints` dataset in the `DataSetName` property.
2. Add Month as Row Group.

[image]

3. For complaints column use:

`=Count(Fields!Complaints.Value)`

4. For claims column use:

`=LookupSet(Fields!Month.Value,Fields!Month.Value,Fields!Claims.Value,"Claims").Length`

5. For Ratio column use:

`=IIF(
  ReportItems!Textbox69.Value=0,0,
  Count(Fields!Complaints.Value)/ReportItems!Textbox69.Value
)`

Replace `Textbox69` by the name of the textbox where `Claims` (LookupSet) expression is placed.

Note the validation for zero denominator in case there is no claims in a given month.

It should produce:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, thank you so much Alejandro